# How to grab $form_state value from text-format from drupal form

Tags: 8, forms

I created a form for my module. I have a formatted text box

```
$form['message'] = array(
'#type' => 'text_format',
'#title' => 'Body',
'#format' => 'basic_html',
'#default_value' => '<p>The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.</p>',
);
```

When I try to save the form message comes back as an array and I don't know how to pull the value out of it.

```
public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    parent::submitForm($form, $form_state);
    \Drupal::logger('td')
      ->notice('text: @message', array('@message' => $form_state->getValue('message'),));
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
$message = $form_state->getValue('message')['value'];
```

Comment: That's it. Not sure why but I was trying to ->value like if it was a node object.